# Faster GPS fix in Android

Tags: android, gps

I have noticed that applications like GPS Status get a fix pretty quickly. When I try to get a fix within my own application it takes more time. Does anybody know why is this happening? Do they use a hidden part of the API to force the GPS to connect faster?

Here's what I use

```
LocationManager loc = (LocationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
loc.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
            listener);
```

I want the GPS to give results as frequent as possible because I need it for an AR app :)
Although I putting settings like 1000 ms and 1 m for the update frequency with no perceivable difference in speed of fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could be one of several approaches:

- Using `LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation` (which, given how many apps use location data, should generally be 'close enough' if not dead accurate.)
- Using `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` instead of `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` to get an immediate rough fix, then refining with GPS (if available).
- Running a service in the background that periodically gets the latest position and caches it (basically the same as `LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation`, but doing it yourself)

Answer (score 3):

Here's my strategy : check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-an/3145655#3145655) StackOverflow answer.